# htaccess redirection for multiple URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have a site with 2 folders */images*, */videos*

I'd like the user that comes to domain.com/images-large or domain.com/imgs to be given the contents of *images* (there is index.html file). The same applies for vids/ videos-large -> *videos*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?:images-large|imgs)(?:/(.*)|/?)$ /images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(?:videos-large|vids)(?:/(.*)|/?)$ /videos/$1 [L]
```

Comment: ...and "videos-large".

Comment: @Jon Lin: thanks, but it seems this method requires the images-large, imgs... to be actual folders. Is it possible to achieve the behavior without the need to create them or not?

Comment: @wolfie This method does _not_ require `/images-large` and `/imgs` to be actual folders on the filesystem. Maybe you require an _external redirection_? Do you want the URL to _change_ to `/images`?

Comment: No, I really want  the URL to remain, just the contents will be taken from the target. It's strange it worked only when I created the folders.

Comment: I have just found it works well, just that the URL needs to contain the slash after the name e. g. domain.com/imgs/ Can e. g. domain.com/imgs also be taken care of?

Comment: Ah, if you were literally making a request for just the "directory" eg. `/images-large` then yes these "directories" would need to exist (given the directives before the change), since mod_dir would have appended the required slash.